# Should std::move() be used when pushing to a list or defining an element of an array?

Tags: c++

For example if I have

```cpp
Object object;
std::list<Object> objects;
```

Should I do

```cpp
objects.push_back(object);
// or 
objects.push_back(std::move(object));
```

Also if I have

```cpp
Object object;
Object objects[100];
```

Should I do

```cpp
objects[95] = std::move(object);
// or just
objects[95] = object;
```

Comment: @PepijnKramer No because it is not a returned object from a method/constructor.  Its an already existing object that was mutated, I just didn't show that in the example

Comment: Ah ok, that's pretty important information

Comment: If you don't explicitly use `std::move`, your object will be copied.

Comment: @paddy Okay, so it generally would be more memory efficient to use std::move()?

Comment: Depends on whether you still need the original value in `object` afterwards. If you don't, then indeed it might be more efficient to apply `std::move`; that further depends on whether `Object` provides move operations that are more efficient than copy operations. If it doesn't, then `std::move` wouldn't make a difference, but is harmless, so might want to call it anyway.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik Is it necessary for a struct to provide custom move and copy operations?

Comment: Generally, no. Often, implicitly defined ones work just fine out of the box. That's the point of [the rule of zero](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three)

Comment: (Assuming its just basically a hashmap- and doesn't do any complex memory allocation)

Comment: Without looking at the code, I can't say whether a particular implementation of a particular data structure would benefit from explicit copy or move operations. I'm not familiar with the term "complex memory allocation". Are there also "simple memory allocations"? How do the two differ?

Comment: @IgorTandetnik I just meant there is no explicit memory allocation because all the properties are just strings/floats.

Comment: Strings allocate memory internally. Assuming you're talking about `std::string`, and WILL benefit from moving. It's generally advisable to avoid unnecessary memory pressure, including copies/allocation, which in extreme cases can cause performance degradation due to memory fragmentation. When practical, it's advisable to move data in circumstances where a copy is unnecessary, and if it doesn't result in making code more complex. Then again, you're using `std::list` so you mustn't really be all that concerned about excessive allocations.

Comment: @paddy `std::list` was just an example of I linked list, I really  just meant to give an example of one linked list and one array type because I don't think an array would make as much sense for a move operation?  (But no ones responded to that).

Comment: There's nothing wrong with move-assignment into an array. It's perfectly valid, if you have an array of objects, to move-assign a new value when copying is not required. You seem to be struggling to understand the difference between a move and a copy, and it's unclear what _actual_ problem you are trying to solve. The vagueness of our responses in the comments, and a lack of actual answers, reflects the vagueness and lack of specifics in the question.

Comment: @paddy I'm confused about how a continuous chunk of memory could have data from a random point in memory(that the local variable is) without copying.

Comment: Plain old data still must be copied as part of the move. But any dynamically-allocated data can be moved instead by transferring ownership of that memory to the other object. Think of it like if your object allocates a large string. Instead of allocating _another_ string and copying all that string data, you just swap the pointers owned by object A and object B. That results in no extra allocation or copies for that string data.

Comment: And would the plain data be copied when moving to a linked list also, or would where the linked list points to just be updated?

Comment: Your local object does not exist in the list, in exactly the same way as it does not exist in the array. The difference is the array uses move-assignment because there is _already_ a target to receive the data, whereas the list uses move-construction because you're constructing a new object. But in both cases, the move allows you to _transfer resources_ from the original object to the target object.

Answer (score 0):

if you want keep the object, pushing back better. It use copy function to do that. else the std::move more quick.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).